# Is there a special name for group by / order by clauses?

Tags: sql, terminology

I've read books where the WHERE / HAVING clauses of a SQL statement are referred to as "the Predicate" (which, using the original meaning as a basis, makes sense). Is there a commonly accepted term for the Group By / Order By clauses?

Comment: If you are interesting in getting into the background, http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Mathematics-Database-Professionals-Experts/dp/1590597451 is a great book.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No there is not. but you can say like

```
Group By -- Grouping Clause

Order By  -- Sorting clause
```

Also, `WHERE / HAVING`  works on a predicate. A `predicate` is an expression which evaluates to `true` or `false`.